# Selenium click on Bootstrap datepicker does not work when browser is in the back ground

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Clicking on the input field

```
<input id="dp1" class="span2" type="text" value="02-16-2012">
```

When the browser is in the back ground, does not display the datepicker popup.
Using javasccript or jquery to click the input field does not display the date picker popup either.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#dp1').click() # works when the browser window is in the foreground
document.querySelector('#dp1').click() # does not display the date picker popup
$('#dp1').click() # does not display the date picker popup
```

are the three techniques I used on [this page](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/).

I run my tests over the selenium grid and each viewing display can have multiple browsers open at the same time, possibly placing the browser page containing the datepicker element in the background, which results in unreliable tests.

So the primary question is -

**How come the selenium webdriver click does not work when the browser is in the background?**

And the secondary question is- 
How do I get around this limitation?

*Note: 
Sending keys using Selenium or changing the value directly using jquery/js is **not** an option as it bypasses the datepicker popup and does not actually test the UI aspect and only the functionality.*

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#dp1').send_keys('02-18-2014')
$('#dp1').val('02-18-2014') # updates the date but without using the datepicker
```

Using selenium v2.39 and firefox2.26 on mac and firefoxv17 on linux

Comment: It will work in background as well.I think you are mistaking somewhere.Why not use javascript executors in selenium.and then try to run jquery script like $('#dp1').click() via javascript executor.

Comment: Well it does not. I have literally tried switching between browser being in the foreground and the background, and the selenium click works ONLY when the browser is in the foreground. Also, the javascript click does not load the datepicker popup.

Comment: Just try the javascript code on the link I have posted in the question, using firebug, you will see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you can use this :

```
 $('#dp1').datepicker("show");
```

While when using selenium.It will be slightly done in different way.use selenium javascript executor while using above code  and then parse the html.You can get better idea via this link.

http://www.mythoughts.co.in/2013/04/selecting-date-from-datepicker-using.html#.Uvr546FdSBs

Comment: That "show" commands works. I read your blog. nice one. I guess if you continue using xpath it would be easy. Because we can get the xpath value easily using selenium IDE. In my case I used selenium ide to get clicking year and month. however clicking day didn't work that way. so I used the xpath structure of month for the day also. it worked. hope someone find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to show datepicker due to documentation (showOn options of datepicker - http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn)

It can be shown

1. on FOCUS of the element you attaching datepicker - in your case on focus on  (not click)
2. on CLICK button of datepicker

In the case when the browser windows is active and you (or selenium) clicks on input it becomes focused and that's why datepicker shows.

When browser window is not active - seems like **click on the input doesn't make it focused** - and datepicker doesn't shows.

Also you can use this way -  $('#dp1').datepicker("show");

But it case you configured datepicker with some options before that (set custom date format for instance) - datepicker("show") method will cancel these options (at least it works for me in that way).

**Resume: click on the button of datepicker or execute $('#dp1').datepicker("show"); but remember of datepicker options.**